# ModulesException: Unknown module

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gradle, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a backend written with Java, App Engine, Gradle and Cloud Endpoints. I test the endpoints with the functionalTests from the App Engine Gradle Plugin. This works all fine.

The problem that I have is that one of the endpoints post a task to a module that doesn't exist. At least on the local development server that is true. In production that module does exist. How can I tell the local development server that that module does exist?

```
com.google.appengine.api.modules.ModulesException: Unknown module
        at com.google.appengine.api.modules.ModulesServiceImpl$ModulesServiceFutureWrapper.convertApplicationException(ModulesServiceImpl.java:365)
        at com.google.appengine.api.modules.ModulesServiceImpl$ModulesServiceFutureWrapper.convertException(ModulesServiceImpl.java:352)
        at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:97)
        at com.google.appengine.api.modules.ModulesServiceImpl.getAsyncResult(ModulesServiceImpl.java:104)
        at com.google.appengine.api.modules.ModulesServiceImpl.getVersionHostname(ModulesServiceImpl.java:321)
        at com.peerke.outdoorpuzzlegame.backend.common.tasks.NotifyBackendTask.notifyBackendClients(NotifyBackendTask.java:51)
        at com.peerke.outdoorpuzzlegame.backend.common.tasks.NotifyBackendTask.notifyUpdateHighScores(NotifyBackendTask.java:28)
        at com.peerke.outdoorpuzzlegame.backend.gameclientendpoint.endpoints.ActiveGamesEndpoint.createTeam(ActiveGamesEndpoint.java:81)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:130)
        at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:363)
        at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:113)
        at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:71)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
        at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.peerke.outdoorpuzzlegame.backend.common.gcp.GCPFilter.doFilter(GCPFilter.java:35)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:128)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
```

Code that I run on the place that I get the exception:

```
ModulesServiceFactory.getModulesService().getVersionHostname(GAME_RUNNER_SERVICE, ModulesServiceFactory.getModulesService().getCurrentVersion()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. Apparently there is a way to run all modules at the same time with the local dev server. Then it can figure out the modules.

If other people want to do the same, create ear module and apply the Gradle App Engine plugin to it.